# How to replace character ' with character '' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want a select statement like this

```
select concat ('insert into Place (Id, Name) values (' Id, ',', '''', PlaceName , '''', ')' ) 
from Address
```

The values are:

```
Id   PlaceName
------------------
 1   Amsterdam
 2   's-Gravenhage
 3   Rotterdam
 4   Utrecht
 5   's-Hertogenbosch
 6   Groningen
```

How can you create an output like this?

```
insert into Place (Id, Name) values (1, 'Amsterdam')
insert into Place (Id, Name) values (2, '''s-Gravenhage')
insert into Place (Id, Name) values (3, 'Rotterdam')
insert into Place (Id, Name) values (4, 'Utrecht')
insert into Place (Id, Name) values (5, '''s-Hertogenbosch')
insert into Place (Id, Name) values (6, 'Groningen')
```

I tried to use `Replace(PlaceName, ''', '''')` or something...

Comment: Why do this at all? The problem is caused by the use of dynamic sql, not the quotes

Comment: For showing what I want to do.

Comment: Again, why do this **at all**? Why use dynamic sql? You won't have any issues if you use parameterized queries. Or if you export the data with eg bcp or any other tool, then import them to another database

Comment: I want a simple solution for creating insert-statements. It's just for once.  and I want to replace a single ' into a double '.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the *why* @PanagiotisKanavos is asking here, user1531040. I smell an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close in your initial attempt, you just need to escape the single quotes by doubling them up, as is actually being done in your first sql statement:

```
replace(PlaceName, '''', '''''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using replace:

```
select FORMATMESSAGE('INSERT INTO Place(id, Name) VALUES (%i, ''%s'');'
                     ,Id ,REPLACE(PlaceName, '''', ''''''))
from Address;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f543fc333c71d11fe153629ce527c3d)**

Warning: There are other, better ways of scripting data. Generating `INSERT INTO` is supported by SSMS or Azure Data Studio.